# Applying t-SNE to data of different dimensions

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, pca, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I want to assess the similarity of a bunch of vectors using t-SNE. However, some of these vectors are larger (i.e. are longer/have a higher dimension) than others. How would I go about applying t-SNE to these vectors (as in in the same plot) if they are different lengths? Do I need to process them more to get them to the same dimensions? If so, would appreciate suggestions on data processing.